# Laravel Schema Builder not setting the right digits amount on Double datatype

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-schema-builder

So, I need to save amounts that go up to `999,999,999,999.99`, and in the documentation of the Schema Builder of Laravel says that I can set up up to 15 digits and 8 decimals, but this is not working (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#writing-migrations)

In Column Types says:

> $table->double('column', 15, 8); 
>   DOUBLE equivalent with precision, 15 digits in total and 8 after the decimal point.

The line of code in my migration is the following:

```
$table->double('m1',12,2)->default(0)->nullable();
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Well for a start 12 digits is not enough for a number with 14 digits. And if you're using these variables to store sums of money, then you really shouldn't be using floating point anyway.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage as I understand the documentation is that 15 stands for the digits (so 999,999,999,999 shouldn't be a problem) and 8 stands for the decimals. Am I wrong then? And why should I be using a floating point? Thanks

Comment: No, it means 15 digits *in total*. Integer types are safer for currency values because they avoid rounding errors.

Comment: Thank you, post your answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 3):

try use:

```
 $table->decimal('m1',12,2)->default(0)->nullable();
```

if your values only positive... then use:

```
$table->decimal('m1',12,2)->unsigned()->default(0)->nullable();
```

works to me!